# Unresolved External Symbol Linker error

Tags: c++, linker, unresolved-external

I have a linker problem in my project. I am using a class, NXU_helper, which came with an NVIDIA PhysX physics engine. I have both the header and cpp files, as well as the other files included in them. In my project, I included the header "NXU_helper.h" and I tried using some frunctions from it, but I get the following errors:

```
1>IOPBTS.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl NXU::releaseCollection(class NXU::NxuPhysicsCollection *)" (?releaseCollection@NXU@@YAXPAVNxuPhysicsCollection@1@@Z) referenced in function "int __cdecl LoadScene(char const *,enum NXU::NXU_FileType)" (?LoadScene@@YAHPBDW4NXU_FileType@NXU@@@Z)
1>IOPBTS.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "bool __cdecl NXU::instantiateCollection(class NXU::NxuPhysicsCollection *,class NxPhysicsSDK &,class NxScene *,class NxMat34 const *,class NXU_userNotify *)" (?instantiateCollection@NXU@@YA_NPAVNxuPhysicsCollection@1@AAVNxPhysicsSDK@@PAVNxScene@@PBVNxMat34@@PAVNXU_userNotify@@@Z) referenced in function "int __cdecl LoadScene(char const *,enum NXU::NXU_FileType)" (?LoadScene@@YAHPBDW4NXU_FileType@NXU@@@Z)
1>IOPBTS.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class NXU::NxuPhysicsCollection * __cdecl NXU::loadCollection(char const *,enum NXU::NXU_FileType,void *,int)" (?loadCollection@NXU@@YAPAVNxuPhysicsCollection@1@PBDW4NXU_FileType@1@PAXH@Z) referenced in function "int __cdecl LoadScene(char const *,enum NXU::NXU_FileType)" (?LoadScene@@YAHPBDW4NXU_FileType@NXU@@@Z)
```

All the methods and classes which appear in the error messages exist in the file NXU_helper, but I really don''t understand why I get these errors then. I know it can be hard to answer such a question without having the code, but does anyone have any idea where these errors are coming from?

Comment: can''t really find an answer there. The thing is that the physics engine came with the files and some examples, and I took the exact code and put it in another project, since the solutions provided don''t work directly. I''ve used many files provided by them and they worked. This one should work too, since the code is right there, I have both the header and the body, but it does not, and I can;t really find an answer to that.

Comment: Show us the command line that shows the arguments to the linking phase.  Otherwise it is pure speculation.  What compiler or IDE are you using (there are many out there)?

Comment: Where can I find the command line that shows the arguments to the linking phase? I am using Visual Studio 2010, about the compiler, I really don''t know where to look to find the version.